# Events shown in real time view but not in behavior view

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

For some reason a main event which was tracked before with not issues now showing in real time when occurs but not in behavior events view (last 3 days with 0 occurrences).

There are no filters which can prevent this event from showing.

Any idea how could it be resolved?

Thanks,
Shahar

Comment: @Blexy sorry I can't. Though I think we resolved this issue by sending the events from client side and not server side. I'm not able to point out why it acts the way it is but at least we found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much of an helpful answer but changing the way we send the events to Google analytics from server side to the client side resolved the issue.

Comment: that really is an extraordinarily unhelpful answer. how did you change the way you sent events?

Comment: Any help as how did you fix this? @ Shahar or @ dax